# I can't find -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=512g

Tags: java, orientdb

I can't find `-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=512g` for change it to `-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=2g` for install orientdb. please help me

Comment: It appears in a number of .sh and .bat files.  You should be able to find it using `find` and `grep` (or equivalent on Windows).  You can also find it by searching the github repo for orientdb; https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb.  If you are talking about the Enterprise Edition, check the documentation.  (I can't see the source code for that.)

Comment: Actually, MaxDirectMemorySize is mentioned in the documentation too.  Look in the release notes for "Release 2.2.x", under "Direct Memory".  It even says where the setting needs to be made!

Answer (score 1):

`-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=512g` is sets in the server.bat (server.sh) to change the value you can edit the .bat (.sh) and set your value.

Hope it helps,

Regards